# Problems with Apache Virtual Host on Linux MInt 19

Tags: apache-http-server, linux-mint, virtual-host

Well, I'm trying to make this work on the past three days ago. So I think a little help from the forum will be necessary by now.
Initially, I followed [this tutorial](https://www.ostechnix.com/configure-apache-virtual-hosts-ubuntu-part-1/), and it worked, but I was unable to access the sites by their domains (site1.dev and site2.dev), I had to type the IP address I used for each one of the domains, but when I was tipping "localhost" the Apache page was loading.

**The situation now**

After I revised all the configuration using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04), the things got more messed up!

Now if I type "site1.dev" on Chrome or Firefox, I get this result immediately:

[image: Result]

And the same when I type "site2.dev". But when I type "localhost", the HTML file on site1.dev is loading:

[image: site1.dev is loading]

I think that I didn't understand which IP address to use on /etc/hosts. And if I have to edit the default-ssl.conf. Many tutorials and forum posts keep saying about the httpd.conf, but I can't find this file anywhere (I'm on Mint 19). So I will put my config files to explain better the things.

***My files on /var/www***

[image: my files on /var/www]

***My /etc/hosts***

[image: My /etc/hosts]

***The folders and files on /apache2 and the virtual host config for site1.dev***

[image: The folders and files on /apache2 and the virtual host config for site1.dev]

If you need more data just ask me. I'm doing all by the terminal though I'm more like an "advanced noob"

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: You shouldn't be using `.dev` domains for local development as these are actually full TLDs now. Consider using `.localhost` instead.

Comment: Allright. Can I use just "site1", nothing more?

Comment: I didn't understand why my question was flagged as "unclear"

Comment: I don't see any flags associated with this question.

Comment: I'm saying that because my question was voted down.

Comment: Have you added the URLs to your internal "hosts" file?

Comment: Do you think that just changing the .dev for .localhost can resolve the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking about added URLs. What I changed is shown on the pictures.

Comment: Don't use pictures for code samples/console output. Use code blocks. It's easier to read and can be copy pasted in answers if needed.

Comment: You will need to tell your computer which IP address to look at for `http://site.dev`. Take a look [here](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/). Using `.localhost` will remove the crazy forced SSL that Chrome does on `.dev` TLDs.

Comment: I will implement that and test again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Burgi said on the comments, I just changed from `.dev` to `.localhost` (resetting the permissions and editing new .conf files) and now everything is working great!

Thank you all!!!

Comment: You could also be using `site1.test`  - the `.test` TLD is reserved for such use.